# objective c how to set maximum limit value on the UItextfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

***`NOTE: Not to set the Charecter limit, asking for Value of the field limit`***

In my application I have a uitext field to enter cost of an item.

I can able to restrict the text field to enter only numeric values , that too some specific number of charecters,

But **i need to restctrict the textfield to allow only some range of cost only**.

i.e i **need to restrict cost only 800/- only**

*if the user tries to type 900 or some thing more than 800 it wont allow to type anymore,*

how can we achieve tis any help plese .. thanks

Comment: Plz use the search.. has been asked quite a few times

Comment: If you like to, you can check out my CKTextField (https://github.com/JaNd3r/CKTextField). It allows you to set simple validation rules (like max string length, max numeric value) via Storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField == myTextField) {
        if (string.length == 0) {
            return YES;
        }
        NSString *editedString = [myTextField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        NSInteger editedStringValue = editedString.integerValue;
        return editedStringValue <= 800;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first set your textfield delegate...

```
yourTextField.delegate=self
```

then,

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
        NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",textField.text,string];
        if ([str integerValue]>800) {
            return NO;
        }
        else{
            return YES;
        }
    }
```

if You have more than one textfield then you need to assign tag value and put another condition to identify textfield and if you have only one text field use same code.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    if([string isEqualToString:@""]) {
        return YES;
    }
     NSString *stringToValidate= [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]];
        if([stringToValidate doubleValue]>800){
return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

Check the above code and it can help you

Comment: That is not the correct way to generate the `stringToValidate`

Comment: Why this is not correct way, can you expalin @ Davide

Comment: With your implementation it's not possible to edit the string in positions different from the end. I wrote the correct code :)

Comment: Both code look's of same.You just wrote same as I except one line

Comment: Mostly it is, but that line makes a difference :) Try to write something not at the end of the textfield in your code and then tell me ;)

Comment: I have edited the code,check once is it fine now

Comment: It should be. But why do you check for `[string isEqualToString:@""]` again when you already know that it is not like that? (if it was, the method would have returned earlier)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62169/discussion-between-ramesh-muthe-and-davide-de-franceschi).

Answer (score -1):

try this

handle the "Editing Changed" event

```
[textField addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(editingChanged:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

and the selector:

```
    -(void) editingChanged:(id)sender {
       // your code

}
```

Comment: In this way you can only do things **after** the editing happened. He wanted to stop the user to enter invalid values.